# Вернуть объект с измененным свойством - JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, obj

Мне нужно найти элемент в объекте у которого есть определенное свойство , я это уже сделал вот таким кодом - `result = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);` , все бы ничего , но теперь мне нужно создать идентичную копию объекта из state и присвоить ей свойство из найденного элемента . Примерно так -

```
let result = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
let tasksArray = Object.assign({}, this.state.tasksArray);
tasksArray.result.crossout = true;
this.setState({ tasksArray: tasksArray });
```

Как то так постарался реализовать, но компилятор не видит result .

Как можно реализовать данную идею, что бы потом state присвоить объект с одним измененным свойством которое мы нашли через id, надеюсь понятно объяснил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `findIndex()` возвращает индекс в массиве - это `Number`, то есть число. Чтобы извлечь элемент из массива по индексу - нужно воспользоваться квадратными скобками `[]`, внутри них указать индекс.

На что хотелось бы обратить внимание - это на проверки, которых нет. Если метод `findIndex` не найдет элемент удовлетворяющий условию, то в этом случае возвращается `-1`. А значит на строке `tasksArray[result].crossout = true;` мы можем получить потенциальную ошибку. По-хорошему нужно последние две строки приведенного Вами кода поместить в блок с условием `if (result != -1) { ... }`.

На просторах enSO есть хороший вопрос с множеством полезных ответов, которые подходят для Вас, прошу ознакомиться вот тут: [React: How do I update state.item[i] on setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29537299/5275890)

Также, полезно читать документацию на MDN: [**`Array.prototype.findIndex`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Есть такая библиотека как [immutability-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutability-helper) (ссылка на GitHub - [kolodny/immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)), ну очень полезный хелпер, который изменяет копию данных без изменения исходного источника. Для начала ознакомьтесь с его *основным* методом [`update`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutability-helper#update), в Вашем случае должно будет получиться что-то вроде такого кода:

```
// нашли индекс элемента, удовлетворяющего условию поиска
const result = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

// если элемент был найден, то поменяем значение
if (result != -1) {
  // $set - это команда на замену значения
  this.setState({
    tasksArray: update(this.state.tasksArray, {
      [result]: {
        crossout: { $set: true }
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Не забудьте после установки пакета добавить импорт метода `update` в свой код:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let tasksArray = Object.assign([], this.state.tasksArray);
let result = tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
tasksArray[result].crossout = true;
this.setState({ tasksArray });
```

или

```
let tasksArray = Object.assign([], this.state.tasksArray);
tasksArray.find(item => item.id === id).crossout = true;
this.setState({ tasksArray });
```